# Building Virtualbox Linux Headers

Tags: bash

I am trying to get Virtualbox running on my Acer C7 with Ubuntu 13.04. I ran the script posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75565/i-need-a-step-by-step-guide-to-build-kernel-modules-in-chrubuntu) but I am getting the following error after this point in the script.

```
# make-kpkg kernel_image kernel_headers

make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernel' SYSHDR
arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/asm/unistd_32.h SYSHDR 
arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/asm/unistd_64.h SYSHDR 
arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/asm/unistd_x32.h SYSTBL   
arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h HOSTCC 
arch/x86/tools/relocs CHK include/linux/version.h UPD 
include/linux/version.h CHK include/generated/utsrelease.h UPD 
include/generated/utsrelease.h CC kernel/bounds.s cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-fstack-protector-strong'


make[3]: * [kernel/bounds.s] Error 1 make[2]: [prepare0] Error 2 make[2]: 
Leaving directory /usr/src/kernel' make[1]: *** [debian/stamp/conf/kernel-conf] 
Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory/usr/src/kernel' make: ** 
[debian/stamp/conf/minimal_debian] 
Error 2 Failed to create a ./debian directory: No such file or directory at /usr/bin/make-kpkg line 984.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-fstack-protector-strong` flag is [fairly new](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2012-06/msg00974.html). You may have to upgrade gcc. Run the following commands as root. (See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44122/upgrade-a-single-package-with-apt-get) for more information.)

```
apt-get update
apt-get --only-upgrade install gcc
```

Comment: what about `build-essential`  ?

Comment: `build-essential` seems to provide [a set](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/build-essential) of packages for building code. It's only important to upgrade `gcc`.